# RegEx for matching specific Excel path

Tags: java, regex

I am creating a regex  to support the following patterns

```
Documents/OneDrive/Collections/book.xlsx
Documents/OneDrive/Collections/book.xls
Documents/OneDrive/Collections/book.xlsm
book 2.xls
aa.xlsx
```

#### Attempt

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+[/])*([a-zA-Z0-9 ])
"+[.](xls[xm]?"
```

This regex matches all the required patterns but how can i just limit to the last character.

Comment: `$` is anchoring the match at the end of the string, same as `^` does at the start. Enclose the pattern with `^` / `$`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew this really helped a lot.
why does \b does not work in Java instead $ works?

Comment: ``\b`` works, too, all depends what you need to match, a string or a word.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew that was a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you might want an expression similar to:

```
^(([a-z0-9\s]+\/)+)?([a-z0-9\s]+)\.[a-z]+
```

or:

```
^(([a-z0-9\s]+\/)+)?([a-z0-9\s]+)\.(xlsx?m?)$
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/dNVUNt/1/)

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/apN6eL/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^(([a-z0-9\\s]+\\/)+)?([a-z0-9\\s]+)\\.[a-z]+";
final String string = "Documents/OneDrive/Collections/book.xlsx\n"
     + "Documents/OneDrive/Collections/book.xls\n"
     + "Documents/OneDrive/Collections/book.xlsm\n"
     + "book 2.xls\n"
     + "aa.xlsx\n\n";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]